# Bring up a specific user's Windows login screen for Fast User Switching

Tags: windows, winapi

On recent versions of Windows, there's an icon on the Start Menu with your account picture, by clicking on which you are able to select a different user for Fast User Switching. Selecting it brings up that user's login screen. That must be done using some Windows API.

I know `tsdiscon.exe` can bring up your own login screen, but that's still some mouse actions away from selecting the other user for login.

I know `tscon.exe` can be used, with some effort, in order to log on to another session, but AIUI you have to provide the password to it, rather than just bringing up the login screen - please correct me on this if I'm wrong. It also requires the other user to be logged on, tho that wouldn't be a major problem for my purposes.

I don't see why this shouldn't be doable, security-wise. Mostly, I'd want to use Task Scheduler to run such a program/script after some time, so that if account1 got idle for N minutes, the logon screen for account2 would appear. But if it's not doable, then t's a matter of hidden APIs, or am I missing something? Because the aforesaid Start Menu button is able to do just that (And now that I think of it, an AutoIt script controlling the Start Menu might fill my purposes, if no programming solution comes up).

Comment: Surely the user can select this when they come to logon

Comment: There are a lot of things the user can do, but this question is about what programs can do.

Comment: It's important to understand that MS design the system so that many things can't be done by programs, and can only be done by the user using the MS provided UI. A lots of people ask questions here without realising that. The classic one concerns notification area settings.

Comment: There's an API but it's internal (and uses WinRT). I can provide a sample in Visual Studio's C++ if you want.

Comment: Thank you. At this point it's enough for me to know that it exists and is internal.